# How can I see what certificates are associated with an oracle wallet?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, utl-http

While troubleshooting an ORA-24263 error ("ORA-24263: Certificate of the remote server does not match the target address"), I came across [this "UTL_HTTP and SSL (HTTPS) using Oracle Wallets" article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl) which describes, in part, how to add site certificates to an Oracle wallet.

I understand that Oracle 12+ no longer allows wildcard certificates in the same way; that perhaps the `UTL_HTTP.request()` call requires the setting of a `https_host` parameter. Notably, the ORA-24263 error emerged in our environment only once we upgraded to Oracle19c.

I'd like to see the certificates associated with the pre-existing, previously-working, Oracle wallet entry. **How can I see what certificates are associated with an oracle wallet?**

Comment: I'm not a DBA, I'm just a web monkey, and Oracle wallets confuse me. Apologies if this is the most remedial question of all time. I promise I tried to search the webs before I posted this question.

Comment: If you run `orapki wallet` with no other argument it shows you all the options; not quite sure what you're after but you might want `export -cert "<name>"`. Also not sure if `display` will list the cert names, but worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

A ORACLE wallet is just a ZIP file with several files: .p12, .pem, .sso, .jks… that you can look in using java keytool among others...